# Select tbody with multiple attribute selector

Tags: jquery

jQuery offers the possibility to select elements with the multiple attribute selector. So I tried to use this selector to select a `tbody` element by using the three properties Model, Erstzulassung and Killometerstand, but I can't find the right syntax. I tried something like

`$(["tr:first td:nth-child(3)[innerText='Corvette C5 Cabrio']"]
["tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)[innerText='EZ 03/2001']"]
["tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child()[innerText='96.000 km']"])`

which did not work. What would be the correct syntax? I also created a jsfiddle example available at https://jsfiddle.net/herbert_hinterberger/0hswyetk/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 padding__top__10" id="row--e6s4d">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped margin__bottom__10" id="table__cars">
                <tbody data-set="0" data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/selfstudy/projects/ad/res/test/212302246.php">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">
                        <img class="img--thumbnail" src="">
                    </td>
                    <td>Model</td>
                    <td>Corvette C5 Cabrio</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Erstzulassung</td>
                    <td>EZ 03/2001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Killometerstand</td>
                    <td>96.000 km</td>
                    <td>yes</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody data-set="1" data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/selfstudy/projects/ad/res/test/212302263.json">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3"><img class="img--thumbnail" src="">
                    </td>
                    <td>Model</td>
                    <td>BMW X5 4.4 i aus erster Hand</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Erstzulassung</td>
                    <td>EZ 07/2000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Killometerstand</td>
                    <td>226.000 km</td>
                    <td>yes</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @caramba: Thanks for your follow-up. Actually xephox already provided a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the multiple attribute selector the model/year/distance data would need to be included in `data-` attributes *on* the tbody, rather than elements further down the HTML tree. CSS selectors don't allow for selecting a parent element based on values/attributes of its children.

As you can see from the [jQuery multiple attribute selector docs](http://hmkcode.com/jquery-tutorial/jquery-selector-multiple-attribute-selector/), you can only select the `tbody` based on the `tbody`'s attributes -- not its children's.

You could instead set the attributes on the first pass, which would then let you select tbody's based on `data-model` etc. attributes as the code below demonstrates. Although there are much tidier solutions, like using a framework such as AngularJS, or at least properly modelling the data in JS (rather than `data-` attributes and then again in child elements).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set the tbody attributes
    $('tbody').each(function(index, element) {
        $tbody = $(element);
        
        // model the car
        var car = {
            model: $tbody.find('tr:first td:nth-child(3)').text(),
            erstzulassung: $tbody.find('tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').text(),
            killometerstand: $tbody.find('tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)').text()
        };
        
        // apply car model into the data-key attribute
        $.each(car, function(key, value) {
            // .attr() is required to create the HTML attributes, .data() would not do this
         $tbody.attr('data-' + key, value);
        });
    });
    
    // get tbody element
    $tbodyCorvette = $("tbody" +
                  "[data-model='Corvette C5 Cabrio']" +
                  "[data-erstzulassung='EZ 03/2001']" +
                  "[data-killometerstand='96.000 km']");
    
    $tbodyCorvette.css('outline', '1px solid blue');
    console.log($tbodyCorvette);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 padding__top__10" id="row--e6s4d">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped margin__bottom__10" id="table__cars">
                <tbody data-set="0" data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/selfstudy/projects/ad/res/test/212302246.php">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">
                        <img class="img--thumbnail" src="">
                    </td>
                    <td>Model</td>
                    <td>Corvette C5 Cabrio</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Erstzulassung</td>
                    <td>EZ 03/2001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Killometerstand</td>
                    <td>96.000 km</td>
                    <td>yes</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tbody data-set="1" data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8888/selfstudy/projects/ad/res/test/212302263.json">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3"><img class="img--thumbnail" src="">
                    </td>
                    <td>Model</td>
                    <td>BMW X5 4.4 i aus erster Hand</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Erstzulassung</td>
                    <td>EZ 07/2000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Killometerstand</td>
                    <td>226.000 km</td>
                    <td>yes</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with XPath, because there you can go back to parent in tree, but it problematic with some browsers like IE9, else you could try this function

```
FindTBody()
{
var tbodyResult=undefined; 
$("tbody").each(function(){ 
var model= $(this).find("tr:first-child td");
var erstzulassung= $(this).find("tr:first-child td");
var killometerstand= $(this).find("tr:first-child td");
if(model.text()=='Corvette C5 Cabrio'
   &&erstzulassung.text()=='EZ 03/2001'
   &&killometerstand.text()=='96.000 km')
{

   tbodyResult=$(this);
   return false;//break
} 
});
return tbodyResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.